# PHP csv import operation framework

Tags: php, csv, csv-import

Looking for a good framework or script that will allow me to import a csv. I looked around didn't find many out there. I am using php 5.3.3

Comment: Asking us to recommend a software library is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one. It works on PHP 5.3.1 onward :
https://github.com/goodby/csv